# Install td-agent (treasure data fluentd) on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fluentd, treasure-data

From http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/install-by-deb, I can only find the instructions to install td-agent 2.3.5 where as I need to install td-agent 2.3.4 as there are some plugins which I needed tested only on 2.3.4.

I looked at the sources list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/treasure-data.list and also https://td-agent-package-browser.herokuapp.com/2/ubuntu/, but couldn't figure out how to get this version installed.

Can you please someone help on how to install td-agent 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Found the packages at https://td-agent-package-browser.herokuapp.com/2/ubuntu/trusty/pool/contrib/t/td-agent

and could able to install the old version with these instructions

sudo dpkg -i /tmp/td-agent_2.3.4-0_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f